# Composite primary key is used only to access records but not save records in data_mapper

Tags: ruby, composite-primary-key, ruby-datamapper

I have an app that tracks a player's progress over a fitness program. So every player has multiple weeks with the same :week_id

Week_id combined with the belongs_to relationship is the composite primary key for the Week record.

However, when I try to create two weeks with the same week_id that belong to different players, I get a "column week_id is  not unique" error.

I feel like I am on the right track because when I want to fetch a week record, it tells me that I need two arguments to get it - the week_id and the player_id.

I am probably missing something simple here. I hope you can show me.

```
require "rubygems"  
require "json"
require "sqlite3"
require "data_mapper"
require "bigdecimal"



DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/prod.db")

DataMapper::Model.raise_on_save_failure = true

class Player

    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :name, String, :key => true
    property :age, Integer

    has n, :weeks

end

class Week

    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :week_id, Integer, :key => true
    property :score, Integer

    belongs_to :player, :key => true

end

DataMapper.finalize.auto_migrate!

@jack = Player.create(:name => "jack")
@jack.weeks.create(:week_id => 1)

@jill = Player.create(:name => "jill")
@jill.weeks.create(:week_id => 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you already came up with a solution, but I'll go ahead and post another answer for posterity, since I ran into the same issue.

It seems like declaring ':player_name' as a property that is a key as well as with the 'belongs_to' declaration, you end up with the same SQL to create the table, but it also recognizes that week_id is part of a composite key and does not need to be unique on its own.  (It appears DataMapper has issues with composite keys split across 'property' and 'belongs_to' declarations.)

```
class Week

    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :week_id, Integer, :key => true
    property :player_name, String, :key => true
    property :score, Integer

    belongs_to :player, :key => true

end
```

Results in the following SQL to create the table:

~ (0.000000) CREATE TABLE "weeks" ("week_id" INTEGER NOT NULL, "player_name" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "score" INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY("week_id", "player_name"))

And your example code works without errors

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up making a small change to my Week model like so

```
class Week

    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, String, :key => true
    property :week_id, Integer
    property :score, Integer

    belongs_to :player

end
```

And whenever I create a new Player model I concatenate the foreign key and the week_id to create the id string

So my id string will look something like "jack1" for the first record for a player with an :id of "jack"

Not sure if this is the data_mapper way but it works.